# Practice in dealing with character arrays that end in the null terminator

Tags: c++

Write a program that ask user to enter any sentence, up to a maximum of 50 characters. The program will then tell how many words are in the sentence and how many characters are in the sentence. Do not count the null character. The program will then display the sentence backwards. Program must use one function that will determine how many words are in the sentence and pass this information back via a return value function.

Sample output follows:

Enter some sentence: 
This is fun!

Your sentence has 3 words. 
And your sentence has 12 characters.

Your sentence backwards is as follows:
!nuf si sihT

*****I have most of it done just need a little help with counting characters and making the function work*****

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

int Words(char Line[]);
int main ()

{
string text;
cout << "Enter some Sentence: ";
getline(cin, text); 
text = string(text.rbegin(), text.rend());
cout << "Your sentence backwards is as follows: " << text << endl; 
return 0;


}

int Words (char Line []);
{

int CharCount = 0; 
const int Size = 50; 
char Sentence [Size];
int WordCount = 0; 
cout << "Enter Some Sentence: ";
cin.getline(Sentence, 50);
for (int i =0; Sentence[i]!='\0'; i++)
{
    if (Sentence[i] == ' ')
    {
        WordCount++;
    }
}cout << "The number of words = " << WordCount+1 <<endl; 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wonder who is spreading the rumor that posting homeworks assignments instead of questions on a q&a site is a cool thing.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: tobi303 this is for learning purposes I'm not trying to get a direct answer to the assignment I just need help

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `istringstream` constructed from the user input sentence coupled with the stream extraction operator to count the words.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int words(string sentence)
{
    istringstream in{sentence};
    string one;

    int count = 0;
    while(in >> one)
       ++count;

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    cout << words("just two") << '\n';
    cout << words("A whole bunch of words!") << '\n';
    cout << words("ONE!!!!") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```